# Upload file in Ruby on Rails: how to choose the folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I wrote a function in Ruby on Rails for uploading a PDF.

The file is uploaded to a folder in public, but every time I deploy to staging or production, the folder on the server seems to become empty.

How to choose the right folder?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way will be to use paperclip
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

You can easily set folder somewhere like /home/rails/attachments

In documentation for paperclip you have

> The files that are assigned as attachments are, by default, placed in the directory specified by the :path option to has_attached_file. By default, this location is :rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename. This location was chosen because on standard Capistrano deployments, the public/system directory is symlinked to the app's shared directory, meaning it will survive between deployments. For example, using that :path, you may have a file at /data/myapp/releases/20081229172410/public/system/users/avatar/000/000/013/small/my_pic.png